# Only last page's output gets written down to CSV

Tags: python, selenium, csv, output, screen-scraping

I'm trying to extract links from pages, but only links from the last page get extracted. How can I extract everything as I move throughout the pages?

```
for var in range(1, 1001):
    page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href,"pageNbre=%r")]' % var)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", page)
    print('Navigating to page %r ' % var)
    time.sleep(3)

elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(@href, "/c/")]')
url_list = []
for link in elem:
    print(link.get_attribute('href'))
    url_list.append(link.get_attribute('href'))

df = pd.DataFrame(url_list,columns=['url'])
df.to_csv('C://users//admin//desktop//urls.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: In your first loop, you are not saving the result of your `execute_script()` call for each page. Whatever `driver` is therefore only has the result of that call for the last page after that loop finishes.

Comment: It looks the indent of the second half of your script is off. The line starting with `elem` and below should be indented one level.

Comment: Thanks - however, I'm failing to understand how it should look like indented on one level. Do you mind helping me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm failing to understand how it should look like indented on one level.

Jonah, see how it should be:

```
for var in range(1, 1001):
    page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href,"pageNbre=%r")]' % var)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", page)
    print('Navigating to page %r ' % var)
    time.sleep(3)

    elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(@href, "/c/")]')
    url_list = []
    for link in elem:
        print(link.get_attribute('href'))
        url_list.append(link.get_attribute('href'))

df = pd.DataFrame(url_list,columns=['url'])
df.to_csv('C://users//admin//desktop//urls.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: I didn't realize that it was that simple! Thank you so much, Igor and others!